# Assign value to field in array of nested structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a function `test` that accepts a pointer to a structure. How can I set the value of a field in a structure in the nested structure array? The structures are created and deleted elsewhere, I just want to set the value.

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} inner_struct_t;

typedef struct {
    int b;
    inner_struct_t innerStructsArr[];
} outer_struct_t;

void test(outer_struct_t *outerStruct);

void test(outer_struct_t *outerStruct) {
    outerStruct->b = 123;                       // set a value in the outer struct
    (outerStruct->innerStructsArr)[0].a = 456;  // but this DOESN'T work
}
```

Comment: Try this: `outerStruct->innerStructsArr[0].a = 456;`  And *MAKE SURE YOU'VE ALLOCATED SPACE FOR YOUR ARRAY* ;)

Comment: Should that definitely work? I've tried that as well, doesn't work for me. Perhaps my problem is elsewhere.

Comment: The assignment to the flexible array member (FAM) doesn't need the parentheses but should work fine if you've allocated enough space when you created the `outer_struct_t` value that's passed to the `test` function.  You've not shown how you allocate the structure; we can't tell whether you did it correctly or not.

Comment: Thanks, it's quite possibly not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete example that should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct {
    int a;
} inner_struct_t;

typedef struct {
    int b;
    inner_struct_t *innerStructsArr;
} outer_struct_t;

void test(outer_struct_t *outerStruct, int n) {
    outerStruct->b = 123;                       // set a value in the outer struct
    outerStruct->innerStructsArr = malloc(sizeof(inner_struct_t) * n); // Allocate space
    outerStruct->innerStructsArr[0].a = 456;    // Assign a value
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  outer_struct_t s;
  test(&s, 1);
  printf("b=%d, inner[0]=%d\n", s.b, s.innerStructsArr[0].a);
  free(s.innerStructsArr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `outer_struct_t` in this answer is a different size from the `outer_struct_t` in the question — and you're using a different allocation strategy (of necessity) from what is needed with the structure in the question.  The flexible array member is carefully defined and quite useful, but also requires care.

Comment: @101 Do you know the difference between a pointer and an array?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a structure with a flexible array member (FAM) in it, you need to allocate the space for the array at the same time that you allocate the space for the structure.

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers
>
> ¶18 As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may
>   have an incomplete array type; this is called a *flexible array member*. In most situations,
>   the flexible array member is ignored. In particular, the size of the structure is as if the
>   flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than
>   the omission would imply. However, when a `.` (or `->`) operator has a left operand that is
>   (a pointer to) a structure with a flexible array member and the right operand names that
>   member, it behaves as if that member were replaced with the longest array (with the same
>   element type) that would not make the structure larger than the object being accessed; the
>   offset of the array shall remain that of the flexible array member, even if this would differ
>   from that of the replacement array. If this array would have no elements, it behaves as if
>   it had one element but the behavior is undefined if any attempt is made to access that
>   element or to generate a pointer one past it.

Given:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
} inner_struct_t;

typedef struct
{
    int b;
    inner_struct_t innerStructsArr[];
} outer_struct_t;

static void test(outer_struct_t *outerStruct)
{
    outerStruct->b = 123;
    outerStruct->innerStructsArr[0].a = 456;
}

int main(void)
{
    outer_struct_t *os = malloc(sizeof(*os) + 4 * sizeof(os->innerStructsArr[0]));
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        os->innerStructsArr[i].a = 10 * i;

    test(os);

    printf("    b = %d\n", os->b);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("[%d].a = %d\n", i, os->innerStructsArr[i].a);

    free(os);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
    b = 123
[0].a = 456
[1].a = 10
[2].a = 20
[3].a = 30
```

Comment: So I only ever got the error because it happens to be the last element of the structure?

Comment: No (the error was not because you used the last element of the FAM array) — or, at least, not necessarily.  You could change every instance of `4` in my code to `1` and it would work fine (but would print 156 instead of 456, perhaps).  I ran under `valgrind` and it gave a clean bill of health (after I'd added the `free()`).  You never showed how you allocated the structure you pass to `test()` so I can't guess how you did it wrong, but you must have done it wrong somehow.